# NFA complexity of worst case is O(N*M) or O(N*M^2)?

Tags: algorithm, nfa

```
N is the length of string
M is the length of Regular expression.
```

In the worst case, a digraph G(V,E) may have |V|^2 edges

since DFS complexity is O(|V|+|E|), here will be O(|V|^2)

So in worst case, the the NFA complexity should be O(N*M^2)?

Am I understanding correct?

Thanks.

Comment: I am reading Algorithms 4th. It mentioned an algorithms which using NFA to match RE, and each round it will use DFS to find out next reachable states of NFA

Comment: Yes your bound is correct

Comment: The reasoning isn't sound. You would need to show that a regexp of size M can produce a graph with M^2 edges, and that DFS is an appropriate way to determine if the string matches the regexp. I think neither is true.

Comment: @Anonymous Actually for an big-O upper bound you just need to show that the graph has *at most* O(M^2) edges, which is obviously the case if you have O(M) states. And DFS is used to compute from a set of possible states the next set of possible states when one more character is added (this is necessary if there are epsilon transitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Algorithms 4th construction of the NFA, the number of edges is at most 3M, so you get O(NM) instead of O(NM^2).